Is `AcqRel` necessary in the atomic read-modify-write operation to avoid data race in a lock-free multi-producer single consumer queue?
Consider this snippet code of implementing a lock-free multi-producer single-consumer queue in Rust
struct Node<T> {
    next: AtomicPtr<Node<T>>,
    value: Option<T>,
}
impl<T> Node<T> {
    unsafe fn new(v: Option<T>) -> *mut Node<T> {
        Box::into_raw(box Node { next: AtomicPtr::new(ptr::null_mut()), value: v })
    }
}
pub struct Queue<T> {
    head: AtomicPtr<Node<T>>,
    tail: UnsafeCell<*mut Node<T>>,
}

impl<T> Queue<T> {
    pub fn push(&self, t: T) {
        unsafe {
            let n = Node::new(Some(t)); // #1
            let prev = self.head.swap(n, Ordering::AcqRel);  // #2
            (*prev).next.store(n, Ordering::Release);  // #3
        }
    }
    pub fn pop(&self) -> PopResult<T> {
        unsafe {
            let tail = *self.tail.get();
            let next = (*tail).next.load(Ordering::Acquire);  // #4

            if !next.is_null() {
                *self.tail.get() = next;
                assert!((*tail).value.is_none());
                assert!((*next).value.is_some());
                let ret = (*next).value.take().unwrap();
                let _: Box<Node<T>> = Box::from_raw(tail);
                return Data(ret);
            }

            if self.head.load(Ordering::Acquire) == tail { Empty } else { Inconsistent }
        }
    }
}

An equivalent C++ implementation:
template<class T>
struct Node{
    std::atomic<T*> next;
    T value;
    Node(T v):value(v),next(){}
};
template<class T>
struct Queue {
    std::atomic<Node<T>*> head;
    Node<T>* tail;
    Queue(){
      auto h = new Node<T>{};
      head.store(h);
      tail = h;
    }
    void push(T t){
       auto node = new Node<T>{};
       auto pre = this->head.exchange(node,std::memory_order_acq_rel);
       pre->next.store(node,std::memory_order_release);
    }
    T pop(){
       auto tail = this->tail;
       auto next = tail.next.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
       if(next){
          this->tail = next;
          auto ret = next->value;
          delete next;
          return ret;
       }
       if this->head == tail{
          throw "empty";
       }
    }
}

Since the Rust atomic object model is the same as that of C++, I will reference C++ standards about atomic operations.
First, look at #2, since [atomics.order] p10 says:

Atomic read-modify-write operations shall always read the last value (in the modification order) written before the write associated with the read-modify-write operation.

This read-modify-write operation guarantees that the invocation of push will change self.head in order and only a single thread will modify the next field of that object returned by swap.
#3 is a release store operation while #4 is an acquire load operation, hence, once #4 read the pointer written at #3, they will synchronize, such that the modification happened at #1 will happen-before those operations that read/write the object after #4.
If I understand correctly, the happen-before between #1 and the part after #4 is established by the synchronization of #3 and #4. The read-modify-write operation at #2 merely guarantees that every thread that executes push has its individual "pre", and they happen in the modification order.
So, I wonder can the Ordering::AcqRel at #2 be replaced with Relaxed?

Which language lawyer do you invite? If you ask about Rust, the tag C++ should not be used although it's mentioned in the post, because C++ is not a subject of the question

Nit: the box X syntax is perma-unstable and will be removed. Use Box::new() instead.

My recommendation is that you translate your code to C++ (it should be straightforward), then put the [c++] tag on the question. This will bring more eyes than [rust].

@ChayimFriedman I have added the implementation of C++ version

Your analysis focuses on synchronization between producer and consumer. You're correct that the AcqRel at #2 isn't needed for that. But it is needed for synchronization between multiple producers.
Suppose one producer A creates a node and stores its pointer into head. Another producer B may then load that same pointer from head and access that node at #3. These need to be synchronized, so you need an acquire release pair, and head is the only atomic variable to serve that purpose. If you change #2 to Relaxed, then those two accesses would be a data race.

Another producer B may then load that same pointer from head and access that node at #3. These need to be synchronized This is a plausible reason. However, IIUC, according to intro.races p21, two conflict actions can result in a data race, it seems that there is no wording in the standard that says the initialization is a modification to a memory location

@xmh0511: Initialization must be complete (beginning the object's lifetime) before any access, and "before" means "happens before". See https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#12    So perhaps not technically a data race as defined in intro.races, but very closely related, and UB nonetheless.

@xmh0511: Last time this came up, the standard also didn't say the initial value was part of the modification order, so the formal rules for what values a load could see didn't clearly specify that you could load the initial value.  (But of course you can in practice read the initial value.)

@PeterCordes I openned this CWG issue to report this unclear part, feel free to supplement what I may oversight in that post, thanks.
